# How does XOR work in C to find a number occurring odd number of times?

Tags: c

```
int getOddOccurrence(int ar[], int ar_size) {
    int i;
    int res = 0;
    for (i=0; i < ar_size; i++)
        res = res ^ ar[i];
    return res;
}
/* Diver function to test above function */
int main() {
    int ar[] = {2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2};
    int n = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
    printf("%d", getOddOccurrence(ar, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Like in above code, how is xor working to get number of occurrences of an odd number in an array?

Comment: write it out on paper. make a small array, manually do the `xor`, and watch the bit pattern changes...

Comment: I did that, but actually I want to know how does that get counted ?

Comment: @bigBunny  It does not work.:)

Comment: It doesn't. Your code snippet does [something completely different](https://youtu.be/FGK8IC-bGnU?t=10s).

Comment: Xor is indicating the parity of bits, not numbers.

Comment: The full code is this int getOddOccurrence(int ar[], int ar_size)
{
     int i;
     int res = 0; 
     for (i=0; i < ar_size; i++)     
        res = res ^ ar[i];
      
     return res;
}
 
/* Diver function to test above function */
int main()
{
     int ar[] = {2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2};
     int n = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
     printf("%d", getOddOccurrence(ar, n));
     return 0;
}

Comment: @bigBunny If you want to add something to the question, especially code, edit the question body.

Comment: It does not. `res += ar[i] & 1;` does, however. Xor does not generate a carry, so it cannot count further than 1 bit.

Comment: @bigBunny Don't post the code in a comment, make an edit of the question.

Comment: Can you provide me a more simplified code for doing this?

Answer (score 10):

This code does not count the number of occurrences of an odd number. Instead, it finds a single number in an array that occurs an odd number of times.

Your test array has these numbers:

```
2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2
```

Their counts are as follows:

```
2 - 4 times
3 - 2 times
4 - 4 times
5 - 3 times
```

Only 5 is listed an odd number of times.

XOR has these two properties:

```
Y ^ 0 = Y

X ^ X ^ Y = Y
```

for any value of X and Y. In other words, XOR-ing any number `Y` with zero leaves the value unchanged, and XOR-ing a number `X` twice with any value `Y` leaves that original value unchanged. The order of operations does not matter. Since `res` starts at zero, XOR-ing together all numbers from your array produce 5 - the only value that is not XOR-ed an even number of times.

Comment: We are XORing each number with zero, that leaves only the LSB of odd numbers.

Comment: But how does that help me in getting the odd number of occurrence ?

Comment: @Olaf What's the point that you are trying to make with your comment? It is not relevant to anything that I discuss in my answer.

Comment: @bigBunny You are XOR-ing all numbers together, starting with zero. It leaves all bits of the only number occurring an odd number of times, not only its LSB.

Comment: @bigBunny "But how does that help me in getting the odd number of occurrence" It doesn't! Your program does something entirely different - it finds the number itself, not its count, and the number must occur an odd number of times, while all other numbers must occur an even number of times.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Suppose this is my test array 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2
I am XORing 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2 with 0. Only 3,5,5,3,5 would be left.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Just out of curiosity: did you ever encounter an array with such constraints that this function would make sense? To me it looks like a typical academical question without practical usage. (not for the algorithm, but for the "find the single only odd element" constraint).

Comment: @Olaf Of course I didn't :) This is a popular interview question, a kind of brain teaser for programmers.

Comment: @bigBunny "Only 3,5,5,3,5 would be left" No, the 5 and 5 would cancel each other, and so would 3 and 3. You would be left with the last 5 in the result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But why would it be 'keep happening ?

Comment: @bigBunny I'm lost: why would *what* keep happening?

Comment: I mean to say the loop would run just for 13 times (13 is its no. of elements in the array) for each number to get XORed by 0. Then how would 5 and 5, 3 and 3 cancel each other? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @bigBunny: You should read about XOR. I provided a trueth-table in my answer. I f that is not sufficient, read about bit operators (also called "boolean operators" which might be a bit missleading in C).

Comment: @olaf I know the truth table. I know how it works, I want to know why 3 and and 5 and would cancel each other? Why they get XORed again?

Comment: @bigBunny: So you actually do _not_ know the trueth-table. Or at least you have not thought about the implications. Instead of commentiong here all time, you might rest and think for yourself. This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: @bigBunny Only the first number will be XOR-ed with zero, because it is the initial number in the sequence. After that, the second number will be XOR-ed with the first number. The third number will be XOR-ed with the result of XOR-ing the first and the second number, and so on. That is how numbers appearing an even number of times would cancel each other.

Comment: @bigBunny try to convince yourself that A^B gives the same result as B^A.  Then, convince yourself that A^B^C gives the same result as C^B^A or any other such combination.  Then, convince yourself that 2^3^5^4^5^2^4^3^5^2^4^4^2 gives the same result as 2^2^2^2^3^3^4^4^4^4^5^5^5.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. `res += ar[i] & 1`; does count, however.

Xor does not generate a carry, so it cannot count further than 1 bit:

```
I1  I2  I1^I2
 0   0    0
 0   1    1
 1   0    1
 1   1    0

I1: bit[k] of res
I2: bit[k] of ar[i]
k = 0 ... (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) (number of bits in int - 1)
```

It does however, yield the linear parity (parity across all bits at the same position (i.e. parity for all bits 7, all bits 6, ...). The result of any bit in res is `1` if the sum of all bits in `ar` with the same bit-index is odd.

Combined with a parity across each byte, it results in a matrix where a single bit error can be detected and corrected, while a two bit error can be detected (yet not corrected).

This was used in earlier days as a (weak) forward error correction for some transmission protocols. Nowadays, there are better, but much more processing intensive, algorithms like hamming code.

**Edit:**

Other comments and answers suggest this is to find the single value with odd appearance. As this puts quite some constraints on the input, it is of no actual usage and purely artificial. However, the application above is definitvely for real (or has been).

Comment: How would this do ?

int i;
     int res = 0; 
     for (i=0; i < ar_size; i++)     
        res = res ^ ar[i];
      
     return res;
int main()
{
     int ar[] = {2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2};
     int n = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
     printf("%d", getOddOccurrence(ar, n));
     return 0;
}

Comment: Stop posting code in the comments! The code above is stripping all of the bits of the numbers except the LSB, which is indicating the number is odd, and summing up these bits.

Comment: @bunny: What is your point actually? Read my answer completely. That is a parity calculation, not odd/even field counting.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't count them. It's using an efficient 'trick' to identify the single instance of a number with odd occurrences in a list. This trick would not work if there were multiple or no numbers that occur an odd number of times.

If you xor a number with itself, it equals 0. This property holds true even across multiple operations, ie, 3 ^ 4 ^ 3 ^ 4 = 0. Therefore, in such a sequence the end result is going to equal any number that doesn't 'cancel out'. i.e. 3 ^ 4 ^ 3 = 4.

Comment: Another crucial property is that the order in which items are XOR'd doesn't affect the end result

Answer (score -4):

Hi here is my code to find two odd numbers and this was my lab task in my college. Hope you will get the concept.

```
    void printTwoOdd(int arr[], int size)
{
  int xor2 = arr[0]; /* Will hold XOR of two odd occurring elements */
  int set_bit_no;  /* Will have only single set bit of xor2 */
  int i;
  int n = size - 2;
  int x = 0, y = 0;

  /* Get the xor of all elements in arr[]. The xor will basically
     be xor of two odd occurring elements */
  for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
    xor2 = xor2 ^ arr[i];

  /* Get one set bit in the xor2. We get rightmost set bit
     in the following line as it is easy to get */
  set_bit_no = xor2 & ~(xor2-1);

  /* Now divide elements in two sets: 
    1) The elements having the corresponding bit as 1. 
    2) The elements having the corresponding bit as 0.  */
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     /* XOR of first set is finally going to hold one odd 
       occurring number x */
    if(arr[i] & set_bit_no)
      x = x ^ arr[i];

     /* XOR of second set is finally going to hold the other 
       odd occurring number y */
    else
      y = y ^ arr[i]; 
  }

  printf("\n The two ODD elements are %d & %d ", x, y);
}
```

and here is main method

```
void main()
{
  int arr[] = {4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1};
  int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  printTwoOdd(arr, arr_size);
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Why are you doing this int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); ?

Comment: @bigBunny: You should read a C book. That is basic stuff. However, the answr is not related to your question. And it does not help to understand either.